# var_dump($_FILES) after submit has data when using 'file select' but empty using the 'drag n drop' feature

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

If I upload a file using the Select File option `var_dump($_FILES);` shows everything as expected. If I use the drag and drop feature `var_dump($_FILES);` shows no file data after it was uploaded.
CSS

```
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
html, body, * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 16px;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    padding: 2rem;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

h2 {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #454cad;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

p {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #5f6982;
}

.uploader {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
}
.uploader label {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 2rem 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 3px solid #eee;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.uploader label:hover {
    border-color: #454cad;
}
.uploader label.hover {
    border: 3px solid #454cad;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px #eee;
}
.uploader label.hover #start i.fa {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.uploader #start {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
.uploader #start.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.uploader #start i.fa {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.uploader #response {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
.uploader #response.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.uploader #response #messages {
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
.uploader #file-image {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto .5rem auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 180px;
}
.uploader #file-image.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.uploader #notimage {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
.uploader #notimage.hidden {
    display: none;
}
.uploader progress,
.uploader .progress {
    display: inline;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 180px;
    height: 8px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.uploader .progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.uploader .progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#393f90), color-stop(50%, #454cad));
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #393f90 0%, #454cad 50%);
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.uploader .progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #393f90 0%, #454cad 50%);
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.uploader input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
.uploader div {
    margin: 0 0 .5rem 0;
    color: #5f6982;
}
.uploader .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: .5rem .5rem 1rem .5rem;
    clear: both;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: initial;
    border: none;
    border-radius: .2rem;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #454cad;
    border-color: #454cad;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="file-upload-form" class="uploader" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" />

    <label for="file-upload" id="file-drag">
        <img id="file-image" src="#" alt="Preview" class="hidden">
        <div id="start">
            <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <div>Select a file or drag here</div>
            <div id="notimage" class="hidden">Please select an image</div>
            <span id="file-upload-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Select a file</span>
        </div>
        <div id="response" class="hidden">
            <div id="messages"></div>
            <progress class="progress" id="file-progress" value="0">
                <span>0</span>%
            </progress>
        </div>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit-button"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit-button'])) {
var_dump($_FILES);
print_r($_FILES); // $_FILES always seems to show no file data when drag n drop used but when [browse for file] used file data is there.
    }
```

JS

```
// File Upload
function tUpload(){
    function Init() {

        console.log("Upload Initialised");

        var fileSelect    = document.getElementById('file-upload'),
            fileDrag      = document.getElementById('file-drag'),
            submitButton  = document.getElementById('submit-button');

        fileSelect.addEventListener('change', fileSelectHandler, false);

        // Is XHR2 available?
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (xhr.upload) {
            // File Drop
            fileDrag.addEventListener('dragover', fileDragHover, false);
            fileDrag.addEventListener('dragleave', fileDragHover, false);
            fileDrag.addEventListener('drop', fileSelectHandler, false);
        }
    }

    function fileDragHover(e) {
        var fileDrag = document.getElementById('file-drag');

        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        fileDrag.className = (e.type === 'dragover' ? 'hover' : 'modal-body file-upload');
    }

    function fileSelectHandler(e) {
        // Fetch FileList object
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

        // Cancel event and hover styling
        fileDragHover(e);

        // Process all File objects
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            parseFile(f);
            uploadFile(f);
        }
    }

    // Output
    function output(msg) {
        // Response
        var m = document.getElementById('messages');
        m.innerHTML = msg;
    }

    function parseFile(file) {

        console.log(file.name);
        output(
            '<strong>' + encodeURI(file.name) + '</strong>'
        );

        var imageName = file.name;

        var isGood = (/\.(?=gif|jpg|png|jpeg)/gi).test(imageName);
        if (isGood) {
            document.getElementById('start').classList.add("hidden");
            document.getElementById('response').classList.remove("hidden");
            document.getElementById('notimage').classList.add("hidden");
            // Thumbnail Preview
            document.getElementById('file-image').classList.remove("hidden");
            document.getElementById('file-image').src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('file-image').classList.add("hidden");
            document.getElementById('notimage').classList.remove("hidden");
            document.getElementById('start').classList.remove("hidden");
            document.getElementById('response').classList.add("hidden");
            document.getElementById("file-upload-form").reset();
        }
    }

    function setProgressMaxValue(e) {
        var pBar = document.getElementById('file-progress');

        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            pBar.max = e.total;
        }
    }

    function updateFileProgress(e) {
        var pBar = document.getElementById('file-progress');

        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            pBar.value = e.loaded;
        }
    }

    function uploadFile(file) {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            fileInput = document.getElementById('class-roster-file'),
            pBar = document.getElementById('file-progress'),
            fileSizeLimit = 1024; // In MB
        if (xhr.upload) {
            // Check if file is less than x MB
            if (file.size <= fileSizeLimit * 1024 * 1024) {
                // Progress bar
                pBar.style.display = 'inline';
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('loadstart', setProgressMaxValue, false);
                xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', updateFileProgress, false);

                // File received / failed
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                        // Everything is good!
                    }
                };

                // Start upload
                xhr.open('POST', document.getElementById('file-upload-form').action, true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name', file.name);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size', file.size);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
                xhr.send(file);
            } else {
                output('Please upload a smaller file (< ' + fileSizeLimit + ' MB).');
            }
        }
    }

    // Check for the various File API support.
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        Init();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('file-drag').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
tUpload();
```

This is what is printed out after pressing submit using Select File.

> array(1) { ["fileUpload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Arrow.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php53E8.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(968) } } Array ( [fileUpload] => Array ( [name] => Arrow.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php53E8.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 968 ) )

This is what is printed out after pressing submit using Drag n Drop File.

> array(1) { ["fileUpload"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(4) ["size"]=> int(0) } } Array ( [fileUpload] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) )

Comment: You shall to use FormData and append file in that

Comment: would that be done in the php section?

Comment: Could you please give a little more information on how this should be done, thnks